# CSS Columns works with all browsers except Firefox

Tags: css

I can't seem to get Firefox to cooperate with my 3 columns. It works with all the other browsers. Please have a look at http://www.usslittlerock.org/Marines_Workpage.html.  I stripped everything off the page except the relevant CSS and HTML. I've worked with columns before with no problems but this time I used tables in the mix. The look of the layout needs to remain the same.  I would actually prefer to eliminate the TABLES but I don't know how to keep the layout style with CSS alone. I've tried a number of different solutions from this site but none work. Thanks for any suggestions you can give.

Comment: Welcome! We need code _here_ - not just links. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @DaniSpringer Seems to me that's exactly what he linked to.  How is that any different than a fiddle or inline code?

Comment: .marines {
 -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 -webkit-column-gap: 20px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 -webkit-column-rule: 30px solid #cc0000; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
 -moz-column-gap: 20px; /* Firefox */
 -moz-column-rule: 30px solid #cc0000; /* Firefox */
 column-count: 3;
 column-gap: 20px;
 column-rule: 30px solid #cc0000;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://caniuse.com/#search=column-gap reports, under known issues:

> Firefox does not split tables into columns

Sorry.

Good new, you can keep you code mostly intact, but replace everything with div's. (this is the easiest way for me to explain it):

With your favorite editor do some simple text replace:

```
<table> --> <div class="table">
<th>    --> <div class="th">
<tr>    --> <div class="tr">
<td>    --> <div class="td">
<tbody> --> <div class="tbody">
... and the equivalent </table> --> </div>, etc.
```

Change your CSS:

```
.marines table --> .marines div.table
.marines table th --> .marines div.th
.marines table td --> .marines div.td
```

Add a few new bits to your existing css:

```
.marines div.td {
     ....
     display: inline-block;
     width: 52%;
}
.marines div.th {
    ....
    display: inline-block;
    width: 52%;
}
.marines div.td:nth-of-type(2) {
    width: 20%;
}
.marines div.td:nth-of-type(3) {
    width: 25%;
}
```

and it will work in all browsers (This isn't a complete answer -- you'll still need to handle the Bold text in the headings and the index-Letters, but I think you get the idea.)

Comment: Well, I figured the TABLES were the problem.  I can't find a way to do this with CSS alone.  I know list item would work but the layout must remain centered under each of the 3 headings. Any suggestions?

Comment: After making the changes above (I think I got them all), firefox now follows the columns rule, but my layout percentages are afowl. I re-uploaded the page with the changes to this location http://www.usslittlerock.org/Marines_Workpage2.html.

Comment: You've missed one, jim: add `width: 52%` to the first .marines div.th CSS. (I know you originally had 55%, but 52% seems to work better for me.)

Comment: I made that change but the layout is still all over the place.  If you look back at the original page http://www.usslittlerock.org/Marines_Workpage.html you will see how it is all lined up - just doesn't work in Firefox.  I'm quite happy that your suggestions have yielded me a working Firefox page but the layout is sort of jumbled.  Also, I think I left out something else - when I changed the code from <tr> to <div class="tr"> I realized I never had any css for <tr> to begin with.  I will understand if you are getting impatient with me and don't reply.  I do appreciate the help though.

Comment: My mistake, I left out the `width:52%` associated with div.td (in addition to div.th). No need for anything with div.tr. I've updated my response above.

Comment: pbuck, Thanks for all your help.  You cannot believe how much I learned from this. With your guidance I figured out the last few things and it came out exactly the way I wanted, AND works with Firefox.  I've incorporated our work onto it's full temporary page, feel free to have a look.  http://www.usslittlerock.org/Little_Rock_Marines1.html  Thanks again.   Jim

Comment: @Jim: I'd never used the column-* CSS before, so I learned something new, also!